# Dynamic POI using Openlayer

Tags: c#, .net, openlayers, ashx, point-of-interest

OpenLayers has a good example which I would like to reuse:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html

This example is working fine in my pc. I would like to use my test.ashx handler instead of textfile.txt in above example

You can see i have replace the said example with my .ashx handler instead of textfile.txt in said example see below the code.

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();  
      // create a vector layer for drawing
    vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Vectors");
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("POIs", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor: 1.1})],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "test.ashx",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
                    })
                });
```

in test.ashx my code is simple. Which i have tested on url and working fine. It just printing same data which is available in "textfile.txt" in given example. see below.

**point   title   description icon 

25,67   my orange title my orange description**

**Code in test.ashx**

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    context.Response.Write("point"+"\t"+"title"+"\t"+"description"+"\t"+"icon"+"\n"+
        "25,67"+"\t"+"my orange title"+"\t"+"my orange description");

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

My goal is to design a handler which fetch data from database via .ashx. But before that i would like to ensure that this simple code will works.But it's not working. Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any possibility that url of test.ashx is wrong. Try setting absolute url http://localhos:portnum/AppName/test.ashx

Comment: I have debug the test.ashx and it's working fine. Even javascript is calling it perfectly.

Comment: Could problem be mime type in handler code ?